# Create associative array from unique value of another associative array php

Tags: php

I have the following list of associative arrays:

```
([0] => ([name]=> "Paul", [year] => 2010, items => 4),
 [1] => ([name]=> "Paul", [year] => 2011, items => 5),
 [2] => ([name]=> "George", [year] => 2010, items => 13),
 [3] => ([name]=> "George", [year] => 2011, items => 10))
```

I need to obtain a list of associative arrays listed by unique values of the key "name".
My output should be:

```
( ([name] => "Paul") => ([0] => ([year] => 2010, items => 4), 
                         [1] => ([year] => 2011, items => 5)),
  ([name] => "George") => (([0] => ([year] => 2010, items => 13), 
                            [1] => ([year] => 2011, items => 10)))
```

How can I do?

Comment: Do you want it dynamically?

Comment: items is in square brackets [] in every line of the code.

Comment: @ZainFarooq Yes

Comment: I meant that do you want to convert array1 to array2 programatically?

Comment: Yes, it's a list composed of a hundred of arrays

Comment: what you have tried for that?

Comment: Please provide a **valid associative array** and also show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply foreach over your array and create a new one in the format you want

```
$data = [
            ['name' => "Paul", 'year' => 2010, 'items' => 4],
            ['name' => "Paul", 'year' => 2011, 'items' => 5],
            ['name' => "George", 'year' => 2010, 'items' => 13],
            ['name' => "George", 'year' => 2011, 'items' => 10]
        ];

$newArr = [];
foreach($data as $occ){
    $newArr[$occ['name']][] = [ 'year' => $occ['year'], 
                                'items' => $occ['items'] 
                              ];
}
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [Paul] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2010
                    [items] => 4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2011
                    [items] => 5
                )

        )

    [George] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2010
                    [items] => 13
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2011
                    [items] => 10
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You're missing an `s`, should be `items` not  `item`, good answer though.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
foreach($data as $d){
    $newArr[$d['name']][] = array('year'=>$d['year'],'items'=>$d['items']);
}
```

Comment: I think you should check this, it will create more sub arrays than you think, and the OP wanted

Comment: I was trying to politely give you a nudge to test and fix your code. But as that didnt work. This will not generate the newArr in the format that was requested in the question. Would you like me to paste the output from this code into your question?

Comment: Thats better :) I fixed another little woops for you

Answer (score 0):

please try this function for listed by unique values of the key "name"

for example :

```
    function array_group(array $data, $by_column) {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $column = $item[$by_column];
            unset($item[$by_column]);
            if (isset($result[$column])) {
                $result[$column][] = $item;
            } else {
                $result[$column] = array($item);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

$result = array_group($assocArray,'name');
```